# Do unused mysql connections slow down scripts?

Tags: php, mysql, api, class, database-connection

I am in the process of writing an API for my website, along with a pretty large class to process all of the API requests.

Most pages, if not all all the pages on the website will send at least one request to the api on load. The most important priority for this website is efficiency and resultantly, very quick server processing.

I am therefore seeking a little bit of advice when it comes to classes and certain PHP functions.

Firstly, it looks like the class I am writing will probably end up being around 3000 lines of code. If this is initialised on each page, ignoring the fact that only one or two of the functions within the class will be used per page, will this make the API much slower? Should I be looking at separate files with extensions to the class for each class method?

Secondly, I currently have all of my connections to the various databases in separate files within a directory. Within each connection is the function mysql_pconnect(). At the moment, I only require these files when needed. So if the method needs a connection to the x database, then I simply place require(connection...) into the method. Is it bad to include files within a class?

I am asking, because the only other solution is to require all of the connections at the top of the page so that the class can access them without requiring them for each method. This is why I would like to know whether having several connections at once, even if they are not used, is taxing on the server?

So three questions really:

1. Does initiating a large class at the beginning of each page slow down the script runtime, even if only one class method is being used? Is this why people use 'class extends class'?
2. Is it bad to 'require()' files within a class?
3. Do unused connections to a mysql database slow down the runtime of a script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, an unused MySQL connection won't consume much (if any) cpu time, though it will occupy a bit of memory to handle the various bits of 'state' which have to be maintained on a per-connection basis.

However, note that MySQL's connection protocol is actually fairly "light-weight". Maintaining a pool of persistent connections sounds attractive, but the cost of establishing a new connection is already very low anyways.

Persistent connections are a quick fix to solving connection overhead, but they do bring in issues. The worst one being abandoned connections can leave the connections in an indeterminate state (in-progress transactions, changed server variables/configurations, etc...) and you can quite easily create inadvertent deadlocks unless you're very careful.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do not quite understand what you mean by inadvertent deadlocks. Could you possibly explain in a little more detail for me?

Comment: Ok. some script executes, starts a transaction, establishes a few locks, then aborts for whatever reason. If it's using a persistent connection to the DB, that connection stays alive even though the script has died. Later on, some other script is assigned that connection, starts its own db operations, starts transactions, gets locks, etc... Because this new script has no knowledge of what happened before, it's very easy to start requesting locks (explicitly or otherwise) that are covered by the old dead script's operations, and now you're stuck.

Comment: Okay, well I am about to rewrite my class.mysql.php file which is effectively a library of sql functions to make it much quicker executing queries. What would you suggest I implement within this class to prevent deadlocks? try..catch..? Although, that will not attempt it again if it fails. Do you have any thoughts on my other questions above?

Comment: Assuming that your script would abort if a query fails anyways, then your DB class should clean up by forcing the connection to close (don't just abandon it). If mysql sees a connection close, it'll rollback/revert any in-flight operations.

Comment: Perfect, I will put into the class. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing an api to serve data from your db to multiple 3rd parties you are better off not letting them query the db, not even through a webservice (unless you have second-to-second db mutations that these 3rd parties need immediately)

Better way would be to write xml file(s) to a protected location and use a webservice to auth a 3rd party and serve the xml file(s).
Then update the xml periodically.

Comment: I dont allow any third parties access to database queries so this is not a problem. I just want to know whether initiating a class at the top of each page is going to increase the runtime of the script, even though I will only be using one/two methods from the class?

Comment: Why do you need an api if it is only you who queries the db?

Comment: Our iPhone Application also queries it. Plus, in the future we hope to offer access to others but at if that does present itself then I will produce an SDK to prevent people from having access to the connections.