# will opening and closing a mysql connection twice slow down my website significantly more than doing it just once?

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to get an idea of how much of an effect does opening and closing a mysql connection have on the performance of a website. Currently, my PHP website will open and close a mysql connection in two different sections of the code. It is simply much easier for me to leave them separate as they are. I am just worried that I am slowing down my website by a lot. Is my fear unfounded? Or should I stop being lazy and try to cram all my code inside one open and then closed mysql connection instead of opening and closing and then opening and closing a mysql connection twice?

Comment: I don't think opening a connection is not a problem until you're executing some DB intensive queries which will definitely cause some slowdowns.

Comment: You fear is unfounded.  The performance difference is trivial if not non-existent.

Comment: answer in this might help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900358/do-unused-mysql-connections-slow-down-scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah...it will effect...not significantly...but it will be noticiable.. i am telling this to you from my own experience...i have done two webportals....in both cases connections were not sequentiay opened and cosed....result was each time client request has to get send to the server and wait for server responce...in such cases if you are using .net technoogy then do prefer to use datasets...because it does not need to each time open the datasbase connection and close it....it just saves the copy of desired(queried) database in dataset and do the operations...thank you...

Comment: it's like you're chatting with all the `...` in your paragraph.

Comment: yeah sir, i know, bad habit, but it will be better if we look at the content not format

Comment: Those datasets you speak of... mysql has a similar function.

Answer (score 0):

Opening and closing mysql connection is not a problem? Speed will become slow when you are using a lot of queries or queries in loop.

For more information see this [How to increase speed](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)